# How do I remove white spaces from an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the extra space for the jcpenney credit card logo.

I tried multiple attempts from border-collapse,display:block and even setting the margin to auto.Any feedback is welcome.Thank You

[image]

```
<table class="Billing-and-Shipping-Information" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="background: white;  ">    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="billing" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" style="background: white;padding-left:20px;margin:auto; ">
            <tr>
                <td style="margin:0 auto;padding:0px;">
                    <h3 style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:20px;margin:0 auto;display:block;">Billing Information</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!--HERE IS THE ISSUE -->                                                                                        
                        <img  src="images/jcpenney.jpg" style="display:block;"> 
                    <!-- HERE IS THE ISSUE -->                      
                </td>
                <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;margin:0 auto;">JCP Card *XXXX* </td>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-left:24px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;margin:auto;">$64.94</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if you don't add an example or a more clear explanation is very difficult to understand what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. Though you can try this

```
<td style="text-align:center;>                                                                                       
 <img  src="images/jcpenney.jpg" style="display:block;"> 
</td>
```

or,

```
<td>                                                                                       
 <img  src="images/jcpenney.jpg" style="display:block;width:100%;"> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the extra white space below the image?
For example, here at this example I did, you can see a white extra space below the astronaut img and you can fix that adding the next property and value to the imgs at yout CSS.

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/DtxmvLB.jpg" alt="Apollo 11">
</div>
```

Comment: It's mostly from the right side of the image that taking to much space

Comment: Can you upload your code to CodePen for exp, so that way we can see it?